# How to make argparse accept directories in script?

Tags: python, argparse

Currently, [this script](https://github.com/awesometoolbox/otf2ttf/blob/master/src/otf2ttf/cli.py) only accepts files as input (via argparse). I am trying to edit it so it will also accept paths as input. How would I do this?

Script (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import sys

def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input", nargs="+", metavar="INPUT")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output")
    options = parser.parse_args(args)

    for path in options.input:
        if options.output and not os.path.isdir(options.output):
            output = options.output

        font = TTFont(path, fontNumber=options.face_index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say goodbye to `os.path` and welcome the `pathlib`.

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path("")
>>> p
PosixPath('.')

>>> p.absolute()
PosixPath('/storage/emulated/0')

>>> p = p.joinpath("log/GearLog")
>>> p
PosixPath('log/GearLog')

>>> p.is_dir()
True

>>> for file in (f for f in p.iterdir() if f.suffix == ".log"):
...     print(file.name)
...
GearN_dumpState-CM.log
GearN_dumpState-CM_old.log
GearN_dumpState-WIFI_P2P.log
GearN_dumpState-HM.log
GearN_dumpState-HM_old.log
GearN_dumpState-NS_HM.log
GearN_dumpState-NS_HM_old.log
GearN_dumpState-NS_GO.log
GearN_dumpState-NS_GO_old.log
GearN_dumpState-ESIM.log
GearN_dumpState-CS.log
GearN_dumpState-CT.log
GearN_dumpState-SM.log
GearN_dumpState-WF.log
GearN_dumpState-STICKER.log
GearN_dumpState-SEARCH.log
GearN_dumpState-WF_old.log
>>>
```

With this you can just pass any sort of file/directory strings and check if it's directory or file, and whether it exists or not. I use this to pass path parameter via `argparse`.

---

You didn't clearly stated that you know existence of `pathlib` and you know you will have to use this, I omitted how this could be used in `argparse` and put more effort demonstrating how convenient`pathlib` is, and how it is used in general.

As you now stated that you do know it's existence, here's how It's actually done.

```py
import argparse
import pathlib


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", nargs="+", type=pathlib.Path)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print([path.absolute() for path in args.path])
```

```
> scratch.py ./ X:\ Z:\

[WindowsPath('[REDACTED]/scratches'), WindowsPath('X:/'), WindowsPath('Z:/')]
```

Comment: I knew I had to use pathlib, but I wasn't sure how to integrate it. The code section you posted seems entirely irrelevant, and there is nothing in your answer relevant to the question, apart from telling me to use pathlib. I don't see how I would integrate pathlib into the script, and your answer does not explain how to.

Comment: If that is the case you must be asking *How I intergrate pathlib with argparse* not the other way around. I'll update answer. As this site is not a *Do a coding for me* site I'd refrain to do entire implement as that hinders this site's purpose.